# DIV Class Into File Uploader PHP Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

This is what sets the class.

```
        if(!isValidUsername(username))        
          return;
          document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML = username;
```

This is what displays the username.

```
<div id="myResults"></div>
```

And I need that result to be applied into this code, so the image is uploaded as .png.

```
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path."/<username>.png");
```

Comment: You need to put the username into the value of a hidden input in the upload form.

Answer (score 0):

If the

```
<div id="myResults"></div>
```

is on the same page as your upload form, you could set the value of a hidden form input instead and then use $_POST.

```
if(!isValidUsername(username))        
      return;
      document.getElementById("myResultsInput").value = username;
```

And

```
<input type='hidden' name='myResults' id='myResultsInput' />
```

In PHP:

```
$username = $_POST['myResults'];
```

Comment: Well, what is the situation exactly? Are you saying there are two separate pages? Can you explain the current process?